# EC2 automate backup requires volumeid parameter and already provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, backup, ec2-api-tools

I downloaded this [EC2 automate backup tool](https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/ec2-automate-backup) and upload it on ec2-user folder. I used SSH to execute it

```
/home/ec2-user/ec2-automate-backup/ec2-automate-backup.sh -v "vol-XXXXXXXX"
```

and returned:

```
The selection method "volumeid" (which is ec2-automate-backup.sh's default 
selection_method of operation or requested by using the -s volumeid parameter) 
requires a volumeid (-v volumeid) for operation. Correct usage is as follows: 
"-v vol-6d6a0527","-s volumeid -v vol-6d6a0527" or "-v "vol-6d6a0527 
vol-636a0112"" if multiple volumes are to be selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quote, you only need them if multiple volumes are to be selected.